# I am trying MERN Stack project getting error in form submission

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I am trying MERN Stack project  getting error in form submission

Form.jsx

```
    import React from 'react'
    import useStyles from './formStyles';
    import {TextField,Button,Typography,Paper} from '@material-ui/core'
    import { useState } from 'react';
    import FileBase from 'react-file-base64';
    import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
    import { createPost } from '../../redux/actions/posts';
    
    const Form = () => {
    
    
      const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
      const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        creator: "",
        title: "",
        message: "",
        tags: "",
        selectedFile:""
      })
    
      const classes = useStyles();
      
      const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit');
    
        dispatch(createPost(postData))
      }
    
    
      const handleClear = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setPostData({
          creator: "",
          title: "",
          message: "",
          tags: "",
          selectedFile: ""
        })
      }
      return (
    
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      <form autoComplete='off' noValidate className={`${classes.form} ${classes.root}`} 
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        
        <Typography variant='h6'>Creating Memory</Typography>
        <TextField  name='creator'  variant='outlined'  label='Creator'  fullWidth  value= 
          {postData.creator }  onChange = {(e) => setPostData({...postData, creator: 
         e.target.value})} /> 
        <TextField  name='title'  variant='outlined'  label='Title'  fullWidth  value= 
        {postData.title }  onChange = {(e) => setPostData({...postData, title: 
          e.target.value})} /> 
        <TextField  name='message'  variant='outlined'  label='Message'  fullWidth  value= 
         {postData.message }  onChange = {(e) => setPostData({...postData, message: 
         e.target.value})} /> 
        <TextField  name='tags'  variant='outlined'  label='Tags'  fullWidth  value= 
        {postData.tags }  onChange = {(e) => setPostData({...postData, tags: 
         e.target.value})} /> 
        <TextField name='selectedFile' variant='outlined' label='SelectedFile' fullWidth 
        value={postData.selectedFile} onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, 
        selectedFile: e.target.value })} /> 
        
        <div className={classes.fileInput}>

          <FileBase 
            type="file" 
            multiple={false}
            // onDone={(err, res) => {
            onDone={({base64}) => {
              console.log(base64.data,'datafi'  );
              setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })
            }
            }
          />

  

          

        </div>
        <Button className={classes.buttonSubmit} variant='contained' size='large' 
        color='primary' fullWidth type='submit'>Submit</Button>
        <Button  variant='contained' color='secondary' size='small' onClick={handleClear} 
        fullWidth>Clear</Button>

      </form>
      
      </Paper>
  )
}
    
    export default Form
```

Error:

```
    POST http://localhost:5000/posts/ 404 (Not Found)
    
    AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 
   'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
    code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
    config: {transitional: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), 
    timeout: 0, adapter: ƒ, …}
    message: "Request failed with status code 404"
    name: "AxiosError"
    request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, 
    withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
    response: {data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…>\n<pre>Cannot 
    POST /posts/</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: 
    {…}, config: {…}, …}
    [[Prototype]]: Error
```

Redux: action.js

```
import * as api from '../../api/index'
import { CREATE_POST, FETCH_ALL } from '../actionTypes/posts'


export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const {data} = await api.getPosts();
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_ALL,
            payload: data
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.meassage);
    }

    // const action = { type: FETCH_ALL, payload: [] }
    // dispatch(action)
    
}


export const createPost = (post) => async (dispatch) => { 
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createPost(post);

        dispatch({type:CREATE_POST,payload:data})
    } catch (err) {
        
        console.log(err);
        
    }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
import { CREATE_POST, FETCH_ALL, REMOVE_POST } from "../actionTypes/posts";



const reducer = (posts = [],action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case CREATE_POST:

            return [...posts,action.payload]
        case REMOVE_POST:
            return {
                ...posts
            }
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return action.payload;
        default:
          return  posts;
    }
}



 export {reducer as postsReducer};
```

Backend:

index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import cors from 'cors';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import postsRoute from './routes/posts.js';


const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use('/posts', postsRoute);  // Gives Prefix for posts route


app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"30mb", extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));




 const CONNECTION_URL = 'url of mongo db cloud database Or Atlas ';


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

.then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)))
.catch(err => console.log(err.message));
```

postModule.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    message: String,
    creator: String,
    tags: [String],
    selectedFile: String,
    likedCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
});

const PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage', postSchema);

export default PostMessage;
```

In client package.js

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:5000",
```

Comment: Can you post the `/routes/posts.js` file from your backend?

Answer (score 1):

/routes/posts.js

```
    import express from 'express';
    import {getPosts,createPost} from '../controllers/post.js';
    
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.get('/',getPosts);
    router.post('/',createPost);
    
    
    export default router;
```

controllers/post.js

```
    import PostMessage from "../models/postMessage.js"
export const getPosts = async(req, res) => { 
    // res.status(200).send('Check Posts')
    try {
        const postMessage = await PostMessage.find({})
        console.log(postMessage);
        
        res.status(200).json(postMessage);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
        
    }
}
export const createPost = async(req, res) => { 
    // res.status(200).send('Create Post')
    const post = req.body;
    const newPost = new PostMessage(post);
    try {
       await newPost.save();
        res.status(201).json(newPost);
        
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
        
        
    }
}
```